# I want to have a list of color in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have a list of colors in javascript and I have a action which will take first color from the list and somehow remembers that he has taken the first color. So next time when i perform the same action again he will take the next color from list and so on.

How to achieve this.?

Answer (score 2):

Put your colors in an array and use the pop() or shift() methods on it to get the first or last element from that array.

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
alert(colors.shift());
alert(colors.shift());
// and so on ...
```

Comment: Is there something call colors.remove?

Comment: shift() and unshift() actually remove the entry from the originating array after returning it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
while(colors.length) {
    var color = colors.shift();
    // do something with color. They will come in the order 'red','green','blue'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with array methods

```
//initialize your list of colors 
var unchosenColors = ['#fff', '#456', '#987878']
  , chosenColors = []

//you want to call this when the user chooses a color, (click, keypress, etc)
function chooseColor() {
  //remove the first unchosen color and put it in the list of chosen colors
  chosenColors.unshift(unchosenColors.shift())
}
//then, to get the most recently chosen color:
chosenColors[0]
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mp3cZ/5/
You have to call the choose color method, otherwise they haven't chosen a color.  You probably want to do that onClick. When the user does the action that chooses the color.